# Call content in a click event function from other click events?

Tags: jquery

I have a click event that control a slideout menu when the screen is small. When the user click on the menu icon the menu slides out. And when the menu is visible, the menu icon transform to a closing cross, and slides back if the user clicks on it. Working perfect, but when user click on some of the menu items, how should I be able to use this code to toggle the class and the animation to slide it back?

Should I put the slide out/in toggle/animation in a separate function to be able to call fron several click events? What is the best option? My question is complicated, please ask if something is unclear?

EDIT:

This was more complicated than I thought! I have tested to put the code inside a function, but then I discovered that the toggleClass came out of step. All I want is to be able to handle this opening and closing of the menu from the mobile menu icon and when the user clicks on one of the menu item. Really preciate some help to solve this or if there are ways to improve this code or find another solution.

This is the script I'm using:

```
    // Slideout Menu
$("#main-menu-mobile-btn").on("click", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var slideoutMenu = $(".slideout-menu");
    var slideoutMenuWidth2 = $(".slideout-menu").width();

    slideoutMenu.toggleClass("open");

    if (slideoutMenu.hasClass("open")) {
        slideoutMenu.animate({
            left: "0px"
        });
        menuControl = true;
        // Change icon
        $("#mobileMenuIcon").attr("src","wp-content/themes/test/images/mobileMenuBtnClose.png")
    }
    else {
        slideoutMenu.animate({
            left: -slideoutMenuWidth2
        }, 250);
        // Change icon
        $("#mobileMenuIcon").attr("src","wp-content/themes/test/images/mobileMenuBtnOpen.png")
    }
});
```

Comment: If you have common methods that need to be used between events then yeah, make them their own function and call them from both events

Comment: I solved it on my own! I wrote a new script that works just the way I want it to do.